# Replace specific html with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, replace

I have a huge checkbox list with different levels and I would like to style it but since all the items have the same class and no id or contact form 7 for wordpress has no option to make sublevels in the checkbox panel I thought I could achieve this with jquery.

The html generated is:

```
<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">--- Checkbox level one</span>
<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">------ Checkbox level two</span>
```

What I am trying to achieve is to replace

```
<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label">---
```

with

```
<span class="wpcf7-list-item-label level-one">
```

I tried with this code

```
 <script>
    $("<span class=\"wpcf7-list-item-label\">---").replaceWith( "<span class=\"wpcf7-list-item-label level-one\">" );
    </script>
```

But with no success, is it possible to achieve this with jquery or not ?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: so you only need to add one class? use the addClass() method...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('span.wpcf7-list-item-label:first').addClass("level-one")
```

**If you want to add a class to all spans based on  their index:**

```
$('span.wpcf7-list-item-label').each(function(index){
    $(this).addClass('level-' + index);
});
```

Comment: What about the three hypens? Hint: `.text()`

Comment: Thanks but maybe I didn't explain well. I have a lot of checkboxes, so for example I have that code 10 times, then I have another with ------ instead of --- 30 times, then again --- then 20 more starting with ------, so I need to add class based on what the checkbox label content is starting with --- or ------, not just the first.

Comment: @JohnSmith. see the update, I thought this might be the case.

Comment: Thanks gdoron, Not exactly what I was looking for but it will get the job done.

Answer (score 2):

Use this :

```
$('.wpcf7-list-item-label').first().addClass('level-one');
```

For checking particular text,

```
$(".wpcf7-list-item-label:contains('---')").addClass('level-one');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$('.wpcf7-list-item-label').first().removeClass("existingclass").addClass("newclass");
```

Comment: `.removeClass("existingclass")` why is that for?

Comment: Removing for existing one as the name suggests, then adding new one

Comment: But he's not trying to remove one in the question. `:)`